# mysql - Why "n" is included when I search for "ñ"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. When I have this code `SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM CONTACT WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%ñ%'` why is it returning all `FIRST_NAME` that has `n` without `ñ`. Im expecting only those that have `ñ`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is a collation issue.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Im using Latin1. What is the best collation to handle this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME 
FROM CONTACT 
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%ñ%' COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa1a0/8)

Comment: +1, Let me give you one demo fiddle: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa1a0/2).

Comment: somehow late, but it doesn´t work if instead of ñ you try to search for any of these: áéíóú (neither lower nor uppercase). What collation should i use for those cases? I tried utf8_bin and it works BUT it is case SENSITIVE, and i'd like to get both cases. Of course I could use `where field like '%á%' collate utf8_bin or field like '%Á%' collate utf8_bin` but i'd like to avoid it. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes this solution is not working for '%Á%','%ó'.If any one have any idea about this please post it.

Answer (score 15):

Try to use a [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) operator to compare strings in binary way -

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM CONTACT WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE BINARY '%ñ%'
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful